# Apply a function to a time series

Tags: r, function, time-series

Hey I am trying to apply a two different functions to a time series. The first function states the problem and the second function uses `optim` to solve it.

I already tried to put both functions into one to apply this one single function to a time series.
Now the big problem is I can not return the computed values. R tells me: *** Error in return(V_A, Vola_A, DD, PD) : 
  multi-argument returns are not permitted ***

I thought of removing the line `return(V_A, Vola_A, DD, PD)`
But if I do this, a value I do not want (I do not even know what exactly it is) is printed out.

Here is my code:

```
data <- read.zoo(data)

cca <- function(V_LCL,Vola_LCL,Barriere,rf,HZ) {
  cca_min <- function(x) { 

    V_A <- x[1]
    Vola_A <- x[2]

    d1 <- (log(V_A/Barriere)+(rf+Vola_A^2/2)*HZ)/(Vola_A*sqrt(HZ))
    d2 <- d1-Vola_A*sqrt(HZ)

    G <- V_A*pnorm(d1)-Barriere*exp(-rf*HZ)*pnorm(d2)-V_LCL
    H <- pnorm(d1)*Vola_A*V_A-Vola_LCL*V_LCL

    return(G^2+H^2) #Summe der Residuen.

  }

  cca_fin <- optim(c(V_A = V_LCL, Vola_A = Vola_LCL),cca_min)
  V_A <- cca_fin$par[1]
  Vola_A <- cca_fin$par[2]

  d1 <- (log(V_A/Barriere)+(rf+Vola_A^2/2)*HZ)/(Vola_A*sqrt(HZ))
  d2 <- d1-Vola_A*sqrt(HZ)

  DD <- d2
  PD <- pnorm(-d2)


}

solution <- apply(data, MARGIN = 1, FUN=function(data) cca(V_LCL=data[["V_LCL"]], Vola_LCL=data[["Vola_LCL"]], Barriere=data[["Barriere"]], rf=data[["rf"]], HZ=1))
```

I expect to get a data frame with 5 different columns. The date and my 4 different returns as mentioned before.

For "rebuilding" the problem by yourself:

```
#dput(head(data,10))
structure(c(75500410877, 77601206594, 79186519481, 80974008790, 
82537645824, 83864068176, 85170542638, 85919899689, 86511152529, 
86661504323, 0.079017183, 0.07855107, 0.077269899, 0.0712223, 
0.069432901, 0.069656866, 0.069367016, 0.070503068, 0.071102523, 
0.073219234, 9.2e+10, 87939600000, 84480400000, 80973200000, 
7.74e+10, 7.45e+10, 70886400000, 67668720000, 64408640000, 61210800000, 
0.028605, 0.030294737, 0.033022727, 0.033166667, 0.033309524, 
0.033631818, 0.03641, 0.038721739, 0.038452381, 0.041755), .Dim = c(10L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V_LCL", "Vola_LCL", "Barriere", 
"rf")), index = structure(c(12784, 12815, 12843, 12874, 12904, 
12935, 12965, 12996, 13027, 13057), class = "Date"), class = "zoo")
```

What do I have to change/add to my code?

Comment: It does return nothing if you add the line ```return(V_A, Vola_A, DD, PD)``` again. If not, it does. But not what I want.

Comment: You may need to wrap in a `list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use the `return` with `list` (if the lengths are different) or a `data.frame` it would return

```
return(data.frame(V_A, Vola_A, DD, PD))
```

---

```
do.call(rbind, apply(data, MARGIN = 1, FUN=function(data)
     cca(V_LCL=data[["V_LCL"]], 
      Vola_LCL=data[["Vola_LCL"]], Barriere=data[["Barriere"]], 
      rf=data[["rf"]], HZ=1)))
#                 V_A     Vola_A          DD           PD
#2005-01-01 83050451962 0.68779085 -0.45110142 6.740418e-01
#2005-02-01 85361327254 0.64400360 -0.32116690 6.259580e-01
#2005-03-01 87105171426 0.60232917 -0.19554222 5.775158e-01
#2005-04-01 89071409714 0.54911211 -0.04056589 5.161790e-01
#2005-05-01 90791410452 0.48899014  0.14996570 4.403958e-01
#2005-06-01 92250475072 0.42087446  0.37724425 3.529960e-01
#2005-07-01 93687596965 0.06307322  4.96737159 3.393323e-07
#2005-08-01 94511889722 0.06415389  5.77931393 3.750293e-09
#2005-09-01 95162267830 0.06458672  6.60665865 1.965455e-11
#2005-10-01 95327654820 0.06656895  7.24865868 2.104595e-13
```

<

Comment: It works. Is there a way to get a more usefull ```data.frame``` which shows different columns?

Comment: @JeremyS.  If  you check my code, I am returning a `data.frame`